# Make cytoscape node not draggable

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Can't figure out how to prevent nodes from being draggable. I want to keep  selection (`tap` event) enabled.

What I've tried:

- `events: no` does not work as it prevents selection
- `elements.on('drag', (event)=>{event.preventDefault(); return false})` does not do anything, nodes are still draggable
- `autolock: true` does not work either
- Can't set the nodes' `height` not `width` to 1px (I need a border)

Answer (score 1):

Right from the docs:

http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json

```
{ data: { id: 'somenode' }, locked: true }
```

See also http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.lock

Comment: `locked` does not do it but you gave me a lead: `grabbable`. Cheers